# Transferring dictionary via post request

Tags: python

I am using Python and try to send a dictionary (that contains dynamic data) via HTTP-Post request to the server.
What is the most efficient way to implement it?

Answer (score 8):

Use `urllib.urlencode` to encode the dictionary as a POST.

```
import urllib
import urllib2

mydict = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
encoded_dict = urllib.urlencode(mydict)

request = urllib2.Request(myurl, encoded_dict)
# now make the request
response = request.urlopen().read()
```

Comment: This will work for strings, but there may be a problem with other data types.

Comment: This was the first answer I came to and it seems there was a slight problem when I tried it as typed.  What worked for me was:     response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()

Answer (score 6):

There's also the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) library:

```
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
```

Comment: host headers are required, right? otherwise we get 400 response.

Comment: Don't think so, the code above gives me a 200 response: https://repl.it/@rjnienaber/CircularChocolateSlope

Answer (score 2):

A good way to represent such data is using [JSON](http://json.org). Python has a [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module that will help.

Answer (score 2):

```
import urllib2
import json

pydict = {'list': [{'k1': '60411', 'k2': 'val'}], 'Id': '775'}

jsondata = json.dumps(pydict)

postreq = urllib2.Request(_url, jsondata)
postreq.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
resp = urllib2.urlopen(postreq)
print "resp:", resp.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Send data in dictionary via post request to server:

```
import requests
import json

print("Making Post Request")

data_dictionary = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
url = "http://enter-your-url"

# Make a post request
response = requests.post(url, json = data_dictionary)

# check response status
if not response.ok:
  raise Exception("GET failed with status code {}".format(response.status_code))
```